# Enlarging the right half of gnome-shell panel?

Tags: gnome, panel, resize

I have gnome-panel with various extensions installed. The right half is crammed so that many items are not displayed (I already removed volume, username, a11y, ...). Is there a way to make the items stretch to the left, to the unused space?

**EDIT**: I am using gnome-shell 3.4 from precise repos.

[image: panel screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/51/extend-left-box/

Here is an example:

[image: http://imgur.com/5pP3L.png]

Comment: Unfortunately this extension does not install from the web (although it looks like turned on) and installing the git version manually into `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/...` does not help either. I am using gnome-shell 3.4 (will add it to the post), FYI. What is your version?